Spring Cloud Sleuth generates exception - rx.plugins.RxJavaPLugins are in unnamed module
We are trying to add Spring Cloud Sleuth 3.1.9 to our Spring Boot 2.7 project, but getting an exception on launch - rx.plugins.RxJavaPLugins are in unnamed module
I tried this in Java 11 and Java 17. It is not a modules application.
How can I fix this?
